# What to do when the FireFoxOS marketplace does not update

Tags: firefox-os, marketplace

I have a FirefoxOS device, but a week ago I tried to grab a new update of the Marketplace app. For some reason it starts to update, but it does never complete. It keeps hanging in "Downloading Marketplace", and after a while it tells "Could not download Marketplace"

I tried several things, multiple times:

- stop/cancel the download, retry.
- enable/disable Wifi
- enable/disable 3G
- reboot
- remove battery, reboot

I also tried to find settings that might be related to updating apps, but I cannot find anything.

[image: FirefoxOS Marketplace does not update]

It seems to be in some kind of routine where it does not allow to download/update that app anymore, but I also cannot open it.

If anyone has good ideas, I love to hear it. Now I cannot download new apps anymore.

I use a model called *qcom*, with software *Boot2Gecko Firefox OS 2.0.0.0-prerelease*, platform version *32.0*.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like the right place to ask this question. You might want to go to a Mozilla forum somewhere.

Comment: You are right. I filled in a bugreport at Mozilla. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1126243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the Prerelease versions affecting with this bug!Update the Firefox OS to the latest version and then try again. It will work then.

Comment: I have the 2.0.0 prerelease, I cannot update to a higher version.